# Add select field with built-in search to Suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is there a way to add built-in search to a select type field for suitlet?

I have a dropdown (select) field with a few thousand options. I was wondering if there is a way to add search functionality, similar to the one available for some record fields (attached image).

[image]

Comment: Your select field is sourcing from a Record Type (standard or custom record type) or are you adding the select values using "addSelectOption" ?

Comment: I am using addSelectOptions.

Comment: Then you can add another text field to allow the users to enter the search text and use client script "fieldChanged" event (or use pure jQuery) to run a search to get your filtered data and then you can reset the available options on your Select field by using the functions "removeSelectOption" and "addSelectOption"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find a NetSuite way of doing this. I went with 'select2' library, and used jQuery to handle the events. Maybe this will help someone...